# Create Custom function to update virtual attribute of point from raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to dynamically update the elevation value of a point based on its location when the user tries to move it in edit mode and after saving it in QGIS. I got a point shapefile and DTM (.asc) raster file.
I want to create a custom function which could be added to the expression of the virtual attribute of the point shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  You had a tag for PyQGIS that I have removed.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3.4**

There is a readily available function **raster_value()** in the QGIS 3.4.

1. Start the Field Calculator on the attribute table of your point shapefile.
2. Make sure you will create a Virtual Field.
3. Expression is `raster_value('DTM', 1, $geometry)`
4. Start digitizing new points. The attribute field will be filled by the raster value on-the-fly.

[image]

(Sorry it is not clear... I am just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each click on the map...)